# PHP Log in Program

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am writing a simple log in program in php. 
All i get is "Password incorrect!". what is wrong with my code? I am sure there is a user and password in the database that I am using.

```
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];  

  if ($name&&$password)
  {
  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Couldn't connect");
  mysql_select_db("motogp") or die ("Couldn't find databank");

  $query = mysql_query("select * from user where login = '$name'")
or die("Query is not right");

  $query2 = mysql_query("select password from user where login = '$name'")
or die("Query is not right");

  echo $query;
  echo $query2;


  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);


     if($numrows != 0)
      {
         if($query2==$password)
         {
          echo "You are in";
         }
         else 
         {
          echo ("Password incorrect!");
         }
      }
    else
      {
      echo ("Login not right");
      }
  }
  else 
  {
      die ("PLEASE!!! Enter username and password!");
  }
?>
```

Comment: First thing don't use mysql_* use mysqli_* lots of people told again again...

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: Please for read more about password encryption and parameterized queries!!!

Comment: No. I don't think I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP.NET

`resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`

means, `mysql_query` was return resource. you can't just compare a resource with a string ( `$password` ), would you?

You need to call `mysql_fetch_`(row|array|assoc) first.

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
<?php 
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];  

  if (!empty($name) && !empty($password))
  {
  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("Couldn't connect");
  mysql_select_db("motogp") or die ("Couldn't find databank");

  $query = mysql_query("select * from user where login = '$name' and password='$password'")or die("Query is not right");

  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);


     if($numrows != 0)
      {

          echo "You are in";   
      }
    else
      {
      echo ("Login not right");
      }
  }
  else 
  {
      die ("PLEASE!!! Enter username and password!");
  }
?>
```